# Android: cannot update textView text dynamically from onTouchEvent

Tags: android, touch-event

I am working on an application that allows user to drag a dot on a screen and set the values of distance for example. What I want is to have half screen for drag function and the other half with gadgets (buttons and textViews). To do so I created a class extending SurfaceView, used a bitmap "dot" and the function onTouchEvent and in my xml file I referenced like following to my view:

```
 <test1.DragView
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     />
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />
```

Which gives me what I want. But now I want to dynamically update the position of the dot. To do so I added setText() function for my textView in my onTouchEvent function:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    x=(int)event.getX();
    y=(int)event.getY();
    bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dot);
    if(x<0)
        x=0;
    if(x > width+(bitmap.getWidth()/2))   
        x=width+(bitmap.getWidth()/2);
    if(y <0)
        y=0;
    if(y > height/2)
        y=height/2;
    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView); //I declared tv in the beginning of my class
    tv.setText(x);
    updateBall(); //it's a function that resets the position of the dot

    return true;
}
```

it gives me errors like

```
AndroidRuntime(845): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
AndroidRuntime(845): java.lang.NullPointerException
AndroidRuntime(845):    
at test1.DragView.onTouchEvent(DragView.java:87)
AndroidRuntime(845):    
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5462)
AndroidRuntime(845):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1953)
```

I cannot use my textView in my DragView class. Is it normal? I can provide more explications if needed.

EDIT:
After using the solution of ReubenScratton I can acces my textView now but I'm getting the following error:

```
AndroidRuntime(672): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
AndroidRuntime(672): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x109
AndroidRuntime(672):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:247)
AndroidRuntime(672):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3427)
AndroidRuntime(672):    at test1.DragView.onDraw(DragView.java:73)
```

Comment: it would be convinient if you can provide the piece of code where you call `setText()` and the logcat output.

Comment: "it gives me errors like NullPointerException" - how do you expect us to help if you don't provide the code that produces the NPE, and the stack trace of the exception? LogCat at least please

Comment: @Guillaume you are right. I edited my question.

Comment: Still not enough -please add the definition of `tv` variable and its initialization.

Comment: Do put that BitmapFactory.decodeResource() call somewhere else, e.g. onCreate(). Calling it on every touch event will kill your performance / memory usage. FWIW I suspect 'tv' is null.

Comment: @ReubenScratton thanks I'll put it somewhere else. And how can tv be null? Where should I put it then?

Comment: One thing I noticed is that your variable "x" is casted to an int. tv.setText takes a charsequence.

Comment: Oh hang on... is the code snippet in a View-derived class? If yes then you're using the wrong findViewById()... you're using View.findViewById() which will only search through child views. You want to use the Activity.findViewById(). Change the line to "tv=(TextView) ((Activity)getContext()).findViewById(R.id.textView);".

Comment: @ReubenScratton Your were right!! I can access my textView now but I have some new errors while updating the textView. I'm adding them in my question.

Comment: @lazeR and yeah you were right too I found the solution to my second problem thanks to you.

Comment: @ReubenScratton another question. When I use this method of accessing TextView my program works but I get NullPointerException for my textView. It doesn't stop the program but slows it down a lot. Can you please explain it?

Comment: Suggest you move your variable tv from function to class and do the findViewById in onCreate()  (after the setContentView call).

Comment: @ReubenScratton I tried what you suggested but the problem is that whenever I perform an action on an element called in onCreate, the program stops giving NullPointerException for this element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question but note that I'm just putting together the solutions given by others (**ReubenScratton** and **lazeR**) so that if someone else is having the same problem he'll find the whole solution.
So the solution: first of all instead of accessing my `textView` directly I had to use

```
 tv=(TextView) ((Activity)getContext()).findViewById(R.id.textView)
```

because if you use

```
tv=(TextView)findViewById();
```

You're using `View.findViewById()` which will only search through child views.

You want to use the `Activity.findViewById()` **ReubenScratton**

And for my second problem as I was using directly an int to the `setText()` function it wasn't working but thanks to **lazeR**'s comment I noticed it and found the solution. Thanks to all those who helped me :).